# positioning an matrix image at the center of imageview

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, zooming

I've created a gallery of images and everything works fine. To zoom in and move an image is required

```
ImgView.setScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX)
```

and when I do it, the image I got is  small, so I called the method

```
scaleFactor = view.getWidth()/(float)view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
 matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
```

so do not miss the image size but as you can see, the image rises above everything and need to stay in the center of the screen.

I tried this

```
matrix.postTranslate((screen_width-image_width)/2, (screen_height-image_height)/2);
```

but don't work.

Any idea? Sorry for not inserting images, but I can not because my reputation. 
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: have you tried to specify the pivot point? `matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, view.getWidth() / 2, view.getHeight() / 2);`

Comment: yes, I tried but without any results. The picture still does not get in the middle. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I've corrected the error, just had to put the following lines of code:

```
RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, image_width, image_height);
RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);
matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
```

Hopefully someone help, thank you very much for answering.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    screenWidth = layout.getWidth();
    screenHeight = layout.getHeight();

    Log.e("", "Image Width : " + imageWidth + " > " + imageHeight);
    Log.e("", "screen Width : " + screenWidth + " > " + screenHeight);

    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

Comment: `img.setImageMatrix(matrix)` was the key for me